# React Native: How to open a Bitcoin URL?

Tags: react-native, bitcoin

How do you open a Bitcoin URL in a react native app? I am using [React Native Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) to detect if there are any apps on the phone that can open a Bitcoin URL formatted according to [BIP21](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki). I have 3 apps installed that should handle it:

1) Coinbase
2) Breadwallet
3) Blockchain.info wallet

But it's not opening. Here's the code:

```
async _openWallet() {
  const coinURL = 'bitcoin:15bMc6sQTiQ5jSqoRX3JzatAbQqJaffqup';

  try {
    const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(coinURL);
    if (supported) {
      Linking.openURL(coinURL);
    } else {
      console.log('Could not find a compatible wallet on this device.');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

`supported` keeps returning false, which causes "Could not find a compatible wallet..." to execute. The weird thing is if I click on a Bitcoin URL on any random website via the Chrome / Safari browser, I get a popup that asks me if I want to open the URL in one of the above apps. So only URLs on websites are opening, but not URLs from inside react native code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like every URI scheme you want to use at runtime must be defined up-front in `Info.plist`. Found the answer here: [React Native: Linking API not discovering Uber app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742013/react-native-linking-api-not-discovering-uber-app)